# Usage of "as of"

Tags: phrases, word-usage, phrase-usage

Can this phrase be used other than referring to time? For example, is it correct to say:

"If condition A happens, then do option 1; as of condition B, do option 2."?

Comment: I've never seen "as of" used in that way. In your example, I would say "as *for* condition B ..."

Comment: @TrevorD Yeah I wanted to add that I would replace it with "for" myself, but my question is if it's possible with "of"? What's wrong with it? Is it grammatically wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with it is 1. as indicated in my answer, it is used to indicate time - not to indicate an alternative of the type you've illustrated; and 2. that it is not an expression in common usage and therefore would not be understood!;

Comment: @TrevorD I was keen to know if there is a special grammar note or historical reason I'm missing and since I was not sure if it really is just used for time or the dictionaries I checked have only used time examples I didn't ask "Why is it just for time?" instead. Like I said right after I posted the question I wanted to edit and add that I would use "as for" in this case myself, but then I thought it would be a useless edit anyways. In any case thanks for the time you put into investigating this.

Comment: Thanks for the response - but, for future reference, please note that the more information you give, the easier it is for us to understand your 'inherent' Q.  You may like to refer to the Help pages on [How do I ask a good question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have answered this question yourself simply by looking in a dictionary.

> **as of**
>   Used to indicate the time or date from which something starts.
>   *Examples:*
>   *‘as of January 1, a free market will be created’*
>   *‘I'm on unemployment as of today’*
>   [Many more examples are given in the source dictionary]
>    Source: [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/as_of)

So (as already indicated in some comments and in your question) **as of** is used to indicate the **commencement date** of a 'situation': it is *not* used in the way proposed in your question; so, yes, it is grammatically wrong.

As also already mentioned in the comments, the correct terminology would be:
"as **for** condition B".